# Exporting data from database with direct download link

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to make a download button on my website that will start a download and download the values from database tables in excel.
The thing is i don't know how. I have gone in to the phpMyAdmin and "downloaded" the webiste, sorted the code and fix it up in my website, and everything was working good, i even add an option that you could choose in wich file the data would be downloaded, pdf or excel. Till this point you could go to my website, choose what sort of file would you like to download, click the download button and the date from the database was on the computer.
It worked fine till after i while the token in the code was reseted after that, naturally the downlod was not working anymore.

So you see my problem, i need the data from the databease to be easy downloadable but, don't know how. I don't care about the method that would fit for this problem i just need it to be working.

Any help at this point would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing some PHP code to do this or do you expect us to write it for you?

Comment: Actually i am using over 3000 php files that send/get/update and delete database tables but i cant figure out what to do whit this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are third-party libraries that can be used to create .xls or other excel formats for download, such as [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

If you aren't comfortable using third-party libraries or want a simpler solution, consider allowing users to export / download the data in csv format. This format is pretty universal and can generally be opened in excel, open office, or other spreadsheet programs, since it is simply comma-delimited text.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=csv-file.csv');

// $myData is an array of data that you have retrieved from database
$csvString = "Heading1,Heading2,Heading3\r\n";
foreach($myData as $row){
    $csvString .= $row["column1"] . "," . $row["column2"] . "," . $row["column3"] . "\r\n";
}
echo $csvString;
```

Comment: Sorry i am not sure how this code works.
If i make a php whit the server connection plus add your code
and connect it to the button then the values from the databes will be downloaded?

Comment: Yes, just point the link on your button to this script. Setting the headers as seen above will tell the browser to save the output to a downloadable csv attachment.

Comment: Seem this is not working, i have made this php whit the connection to the server and when i hit the download button all i get is an empty csv file.